# create a fluctuating copy of a list only if it does not have a zero

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have an excel sheet that looks like this:

```
 Ingredient      Amount
 Bananas         2
 Apples          0
 Eggs            10
 Jelly           0
 Pancake         0
 Bread           1
```

I want this same list in another sheet in excel, but ignoring all the ingredients whose amounts are zero. So it should look like this:

```
 Ingredient     Amount
 Bananas        2
 Eggs           10
 Bread          1
```

I am not sure how to write a formula which would allow the list to be converted without leaving large gaping white holes where the original "zero" items were.]

I cannot just copy and paste the non-zero ingredients because I need the list to be fluctuating because the ingredients and their amounts will be constantly updating. And there are hundreds of ingredients.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try anything yourself first?

Comment: I have an IF statement (IF cell=0,"", ingredient), but that leaves holes in the final sheet. Meaning where there were 0 amounts, there are just empty cells . I am not sure how to change the statement to say IF(cell=0, search for other non zero cells, ingredient)

Comment: sort the list by _Amount_ in descending order. then hide all _zero_ rows

Answer (score 0):

HEre ya go, You have to figure out how to fire the code when the worksheet changes

```
Private Sub grocerylist()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 2) <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print ; arr(i, 2)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(Sheet4.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = arr(i, 1)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(Sheet4.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = arr(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```